# How set the number of yticks with yticks()

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to set the number of ticks in a plot. Actually I am able to print just the min and the max ticks.

```
loss = np.array(loss).astype(np.float)
plt.plot(loss)
t = [loss.min(), loss.max()]
plt.yticks(t, t)
plt.title('andamento loss')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.show()
```

[image]

How can I get some middle ticks?

Comment: `t = np.linspace(loss.min(), loss.max(), N)`?

Comment: @TomdeGeus thanks perfect